# Where are orientation change event listeners shown in Chrome dev tools?

Tags: android, google-chrome-devtools, remote-debugging, orientation-changes

I want to check that I'm indeed setting orientation-change event listeners for a webpage on an Android tablet, but I don't know where this would appear in Chrome dev tools. I'm not seeing them in the Event Listeners panel of the Elements tab, but not sure I should expect to, since this panel seems to be devoted to listeners set on particular elements of the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

In the `Device` section of the `Event Listener Breakpoints` pane you can check the `deviceorientation` and `devicemotion` events to break on.